# How to synchronise changes in Active Directory with SharePoint profile info

Tags: active-directory, profile-sync, 2007

I recently had an incident where the email details of a SharePoint user were changed in Active Directory. These changes were not transferred into SharePoint and I had a problem in one of my web parts which uses the SPUser object to get the users email address.

Is there a way to configure SharePoint 2007 to synchronise such data automatically?

** Update ** 
I changed my email address in AD and started a full profile import. I opened my user settings but see no change in my profile - it still shows my old email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the import did you check the email address listed in the central profile?  There are two aspects to the Profile Sync; the first brings it from AD or other source and into the central User Profiles and the second pushes it to the User Information Lists of each Site Collection via Timer Job.  This last step is what gets the info available on the sites.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What exactly do you mean by 'Timer Job'? Where do I find it?

Comment: The best way to check this is to run the following command.
stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0 
This will tell you which site collections have not synchronized today.  If there are any listed then there is a problem.  You can correct the issue by running
stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0
This doesn't delete anything, it simply resets a bit in the site's configuration and gets it to sync during the next run.  The timer job runs every two hours I believe by default, but it can be configured.  More info can be found here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263196%28office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about sp 2007 you can do it from your ssp. Go to central admin --> shared services (your sites ssp) --> under User Profiles and My Site header there is "User profiles and properties" link. after you click it,you can see the choices you ask for. For once you can use "Start full import" or you can schedule also.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that. I changed my email address in AD and started a full import. I see no change to my profile in Sharepoint (yes, it is 2007)

Comment: you must also delete that user from your site collection and add him again